# REST web service keeps first POST parametrs

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a web service in REST, designed with Java and deployed on Tomcat. This is the web service structure:

```
@Path("Personas")
public class Personas {



    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ServiceResource
     */
    public Personas() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String consultarEdad (@QueryParam("nombre") String nombre) {

        ConectorCliente c = new ConectorCliente("root", "cafe.sql", "test");

        int edad = c.consultarEdad(nombre);
        if (edad == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return "-1";
        return String.valueOf(edad);
    }


    @POST
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String insertarPersona(@QueryParam("nombre") String msg, @QueryParam("edad") int edad) {

        ConectorCliente c = new ConectorCliente("usr", "passwd", "dbname");
        c.agregar(msg, edad);
        return "listo";
    }
}
```

Where `ConectorCliente` class is MySQL connector and querying class.

So, I had tested this with the `@GET` actually doing ***POST*** work, any user inputed data and information from ma Java FX app and it went direct to webservice's database.

However, I changed so the *CREATE* operation was performed through a webservice responding to an actual *POST* HTTP request.

However, when I run the client and add some info, parameters go OK, but in next time I input different parameters it'll input the same. I run this several times and I can't get the reason of it.

This is the clients code:

```
public class WebServicePersonasConsumer {
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/serviciosweb/";

    public WebServicePersonasConsumer() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("Personas");
    }


    public <T> T insertarPersona(Class<T> responseType, String nombre, String edad) throws ClientErrorException {
        String[] queryParamNames = new String[]{"nombre", "edad"};
        String[] queryParamValues = new String[]{nombre, edad};
        ;
        javax.ws.rs.core.Form form = getQueryOrFormParams(queryParamNames, queryParamValues);
        javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = form.asMap();
        for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            java.util.List<String> list = entry.getValue();
            String[] values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
            webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), (Object[]) values);
        }
        return webTarget.request().post(null, responseType);
    }


    public <T> T consultarEdad(Class<T> responseType, String nombre) throws ClientErrorException {
        String[] queryParamNames = new String[]{"nombre"};
        String[] queryParamValues = new String[]{nombre};
        ;
        javax.ws.rs.core.Form form = getQueryOrFormParams(queryParamNames, queryParamValues);
        javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = form.asMap();
        for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            java.util.List<String> list = entry.getValue();
            String[] values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
            webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), (Object[]) values);
        }
        return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(responseType);
    }

    private Form getQueryOrFormParams(String[] paramNames, String[] paramValues) {
        Form form = new javax.ws.rs.core.Form();
        for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.length; i++) {
            if (paramValues[i] != null) {
                form = form.param(paramNames[i], paramValues[i]);
            }
        }
        return form;
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }

}
```

And this this the code when I perform the operations in a Java FX app:

```
String nombre = nombreTextField.getText();
String edad = edadTextField.getText();
String insertToDatabase = consumidor.insertarPersona(String.class, nombre, edad);
```

So, as parameters are taken from TextFields, is quite odd why second, third, fourth and so on POSTS *post* the SAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you do not make webTarget an instance variable and instead make a new one with each method that it is used.

```
public <T> T insertarPersona(Class<T> responseType, String nombre, String edad) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget = webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("Personas");
    String[] queryParamNames = new String[]{"nombre", "edad"};
    String[] queryParamValues = new String[]{nombre, edad};
    ;
    javax.ws.rs.core.Form form = getQueryOrFormParams(queryParamNames, queryParamValues);
    javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = form.asMap();
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        java.util.List<String> list = entry.getValue();
        String[] values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), (Object[]) values);
    }
    return webTarget.request().post(null, responseType);
}


public <T> T consultarEdad(Class<T> responseType, String nombre) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget = webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("Personas");
    String[] queryParamNames = new String[]{"nombre"};
    String[] queryParamValues = new String[]{nombre};
    ;
    javax.ws.rs.core.Form form = getQueryOrFormParams(queryParamNames, queryParamValues);
    javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = form.asMap();
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        java.util.List<String> list = entry.getValue();
        String[] values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), (Object[]) values);
    }
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(responseType);
}
```